# Enabling secure boot on LENOVO M93p Desktop (ThinkCentre) - Type 10AA

Tags: boot, bios, intune

In the endpoint admin center my device is marked as NOT Compliant and he is showing me this : Require Secure Boot to be enabled on the device,

in this article : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/intune/secure-boot-enabled-device-shows-not-compli... they mentioned some requirement that are not as mine: -my TPM version is not 2.0, its 1.2, i don't know how to upgrade that, - my BIOS mode is UEFI, -but the PCR7 Configuration is not bound and it is shown as Binding Not Possible,

How can i fix that please ?

Not Compliant

[image: Not Compliant]

TPM version

[image: TPM version]

Binding not possible

[image: Binding not possible]

Bios Mode:

[image]

Comment: You can't fix the TPM version without replacing hardware.  You can't fix the BIOS mode without converting MBR to GPT, but your system, must support UEFI in order to do that.  Both of these issues are probably issues that cannot be solved without replacing hardware.  Secure Boot only works with UEFI.

Comment: From your screenshots, it seems that Secure Mode is indeed enabled. You should contact the administrator of the endpoint admin center to find out why your computer is wrongly reported.

Comment: If Secure Boot is indeed enabled it also means that Windows is installed in UEFI mode.  PCR7 is related to BitLocker, which makes sense, since you have TPM 1.2 hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound My partition is already on GPT style